# Typescript access object property type without triggering circular reference

Tags: typescript

I have 2 objects: a box and a bag. The bag has 1 property that references the box & another property that is being referenced by the box. Therefore, the properties themselves do not create a circular reference. However, the object overall is a circular reference.

How can I get the `typeof` an object property without typescript first checking for a circular reference across all properties?

```
class Box<T> {
  constructor() {}
}

const box = new Box<BoxReturnType>() // MUST be of type Box<true>
const TRUE = true
const bag = {
  aToB: TRUE,
  bToA: box
}
type BoxReturnType = typeof TRUE // this works! But I need to grab this value from inside the bag
type BoxReturnType = typeof bag.aToB // this is what I want to do, but does not work
type BoxReturnType = (typeof bag)['aToB'] // this does not work
```

Comment: You would need `as const` to get `true` instead of `boolean` in your second and third examples.  Those will return the correct types if we are not also using them as the generic for `box`.  This circular reference seems like a bad design that needs to be rethought, but this is such a contrived example that it's hard for me to know how you would rethink the actual usage in your app.  Here, you would want to create your variable `aToB` or `TRUE` first and use it to type both the box and the bag.

Comment: i want to access `typeof aToB` without typescript first calculating `typeof bag`, since that call will result in a circular reference